# Prevent Highchart redraw twitch

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've used AddPoint repeatedly on a scatter Highchart to show some data evolution, using

```
setinterval()
```

When the chart updates the axes' ranges as a consequence of the presence of new data points, the chart sometimes "twitches" as the data distribution is not longer well balanced around the origin:

http://jsfiddle.net/dhigger/qfxe87tr/

I would like to keep the redrawing of the axes to accommodate various data distributions, so one solution would be to keep the origin at the centre of the graph at all times, and scale positive and negative of an axis together, and always scale up. But I can't see how to achieve these.

Is there a way to avoid the twitch?

Answer (score 1):

Those "twitches" are coming from Highcharts' native axis auto-scaling. You can fix the `xAxis` so your chart won't move anymore. For example, I managed to have your JSFiddle working by adding `min: -15` for the `xAxis`:

```
    xAxis: {
        plotLines: [{
            color: '#FA5858',
            width: 1,
            value: 0,
            zIndex: 2
        }],
        minRange: 30,
        min: -15,
        gridLineWidth: 1
    }
```

See the JSFiddle working with not "twitches" **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/qfxe87tr/1/)**.

Comment: Thanks; this solution sacrifices the axis-scaling functionality, so the extent of the data must be known beforehand if it is to remain visible, and the "zooming out" feeling, as higher-magnitude data added, is lost. But the twitch/jerk is gone.

Comment: Yes you're right, I didn't know your code behavior. If you have to keep axis auto scaling, we need to find a better solution indeed.

Comment: Building on the answer from @Kabulan0lak I found a way using `setExtremes`; I've posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

After setting the limits of the axes (per @Kabulan0lak's answer), I found that I could monotonically increase both positive and negative axis limits by keep track of the largest-magnitude data values and then re-set the max and min limits of the axes manually using `setExtremes` ([manual](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setExtremes)).

e.g. `chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(min_x,max_x);`

Updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dhigger/qfxe87tr/3/